# Extracting data from txt that has some structure with Python

Tags: python, dataframe, parsing, text

I've been looking for a solution without success.

The idea is to pull the text file and convert the data into a dataframe. I made it as far as reading the file into lines and I know I can parse it with regex but can't figure it out. My best guess would be to start reading at line 17 and grab the strings that are bound by several spaces before and after the string until you reach the Amendments or ---- line.

Link to a sample file is below. The files are all the same and sometimes it has two sections (Licenses and Amendments). Ideally I would like to put the Amendments section into a second dataframe as well but the structure is different.

https://www.aer.ca/data/well-lic/WELLS0120.TXT

Comment: Please share what you've already done, and which part specifically you're struggling with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.split` to split your data

```
for line in lines:
    print(re.split('[\s]{2,}', line.strip()))
```

outputs

```
...
['HHR HZ KARR 16-13-64-3', '0497452', 'ALBERTA CROWN', '861.9M']
['100/16-13-064-03W6/00', 'S', '481.4M', 'W', '421.6M', 'GRANDE PRAIRIE', '5967.0M']
['DEV (C)', 'KARR', 'MONTNEY FM']
['HORIZONTAL', 'NEW', 'PRODUCTION', 'CRUDE OIL']
['HAMMERHEAD RESOURCES INC.', '10-15-064-03W6']
...
```

Depending on what data you want to extract, you might want to filter some of the lines out with some if statements and such.

Regex explanation

> **[\s]{2,}**
>   `{2,}` Quantifier — Matches between 2 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>   `\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)

Edit based on your comment. If you know your text's positions you can do something similar to this. You will however need to do some edits / applying some logic to capture your data properly

```
for line in lines:
    positions = [4, 41, 51, 72]
    for pos in positions:
        print(re.split('[\s]{2,}', line[pos:].strip())[0])
```

Comment: Thanks so much Kasem. I can definitely take it from there.

I had a few issues though, some strings are being split in the wrong places, would it be possible to split at locations in the line? and then removing the spaces with regex?

Comment: Assuming you know what location the string you want is, you can use string indices.
line[40:] would return the characters 41 and above of that line. Check the updated answer